# Define bins/subgroups (from continuous variable) to be plotted in box plot (ggplot in R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the iris dataset as an example, I would like to draw a boxplot (for setosa species only) with `Sepal.Length` on the x-axis and `Petal.Length` on the y-axis. However, this first requires binning of continuous `Sepal.Length` data for the x-axis into groups: `Sepal.Length < 4.7, Sepal.Length 4.7 - 5, Sepal.Length 5 - 5.2 and Sepal.Length > 5.2.` Second, it requires grouping together the first and third group. I tried the code below, but this does not work. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
library(ggplot2)
bin1 <- iris[iris$Sepal.Length < 4.7, ]
bin2 <- iris[iris$Sepal.Length >=4.7 & <5, ]
bin3 <- iris[iris$Sepal.Length >=5 & <5.2, ]
bin4 <- iris[iris$Sepal.Length >=5.2, ]
binA <- bin1 + bin3
order <- c(bin2, binA, bin4)
ggboxplot(iris[iris$Species == "setosa", ], x="Sepal.Length", y="Petal.Length") + scale_x_discrete(limits=order)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `cut` function to do what you are doing. Afterwards, you could then use the `fct_collapse` to modify your cut points. You could do something like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)

iris %>% 
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>% 
  mutate(sub_species = cut(Sepal.Length, breaks = c(-Inf, 4.7, 5, 5.2, Inf))) %>% 
  mutate(sub_species = fct_collapse(sub_species,
                                    combined = c("(-Inf,4.7]", "(5.2, Inf]"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sub_species, Petal.Length))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

And that will give you want you want.

Alternatively, you could replace the `cut` function and use `dplyr`'s case when function that would look like:

```
iris %>% 
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>% 
  # Case when to cases
  mutate(sub_a = case_when( Sepal.Length < 4.7~"A",
                            Sepal.Length < 5~ "B",
                            Sepal.Length < 5.2~ "C",
                            TRUE~"D")) %>% 
  # Collapse A and D
  mutate(collapsed = ifelse(sub_a %in% c("A", "D"), "combined", sub_a)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(collapsed, Petal.Length))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

In OP comment the question was expanded to include creation of several other sub-classes. To solve this I will use the `mutate` function to make a few extra sub-categories, then use the `gather` function to pull them all into a single column while preserving the data within each subclass (e.g. keeping the counts correct).

```
iris %>% 
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>% 
  # Case when to cases
  mutate(sub_a = case_when( Sepal.Length < 4.7~"A",
                            Sepal.Length < 5~ "B",
                            Sepal.Length < 5.2~ "C",
                            TRUE~"D")) %>% 
  # Collapse A and D
  mutate(collapsed1 = ifelse(sub_a %in% c("A", "C"), "A+C", sub_a)) %>% 
  mutate(collapsed2 = ifelse(sub_a %in% c("A", "C", "D"), "A+C+D", sub_a)) %>% 
  # Pull all the new categories together into a new column called subclass
  gather(new_cat, subclass, sub_a:collapsed2) %>% 
  # Filter to desired
  filter(subclass %in% c("B", "A+C", "D", "A+C+D")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(subclass, Petal.Length))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez, no problem! Glad to help.

Comment: Thanks again. I encountered another problem that I would like to implement. In addition to plotting "B", "C" and "combined", I would like to include a fourth box consisting of "A", "C" and "D" combined. After mutating, I could not figure out how to do this. (I am more familiar with the non-pipe scripting.) I would appreciate your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: To be completely clear, I would like to plot: "B", "A+C", "D", "A+C+D". Thank you.

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez check updated answer. I think that has what you want.